# How to find all combinations of a given set of numbers

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

I came across a problem where say I have a set of numbers (1,2). How do I get all possible combinations of the positive and negatives in the set. 
My result set should be 
1,2
-1,2
1,-2
-1,-2

I started off suming the numbers and putting  a coefficient in front of each of them. If your numbers are A1..AN, you add N coefficients (C1..CN) and sum. In this case the coeeficients would be 1 amd -1. Similar to solving a multivalued polynomial I guess.

How do I get all possible combinations though ? ANy help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
set={1,2};
Tuples[Transpose[{set,-1*set}]]
```

which gives you

```
{{1,2},{1,-2},{-1,2},{-1,-2}}
```

And that will work with sets containing any (reasonable) number of elements, even including symbols.